# Understanding Bernoulli's Theorem in games of chance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Statement :- Let $A$ denote an event whose probability of occurrence in a single trial is $p$. If $k$ denotes the number of occurrences of $A$ in $n$ independent trials, then

$$P\left(\left|\frac kn - p\right|> \epsilon\right) \lt \frac{pq}{n \epsilon ^2}$$

Someone please help me understanding this

I understood the proof of the inequality but I am not able to infer things from it.

**More info** :
I am studying the subject by myself and I reached here.
I am studying from Probability, Random Variables and Stochastic processes (By Athanasios Papoulis and S. Unnikrishna Pillai) and I dont know any generalized theorems of above...

**edit : What the textbook has said** : The inequality above states that the frequency definition of probability of an event $\frac kn$ and its axiomatic definition p can be made compatible to any degree of accuracy with probability 1 or with almost certainity.

In other words, given two positive numbers $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ the probability of the inequality will be greater than $1-\delta$, provided the number of trials is above a certain limit

Comment: It's Chebyshev's inequality that bounds probability of deviation from the mean. There are better, stronger, exponential-type Chernoff-Hoeffding bounds for the binomial.

Comment: @A.S. can you please be elaborate....

Comment: Sorry, I will delete "game theory" from the tags...

Comment: But why!! @Stef

Comment: @Stef, This is certainly not game theory, Stef is right.

Comment: I included the tag because this theorem is the heart for dealing with the games of chance. But no problem I am just looking for my answer @Stef

Answer (score 3):

"In $n$ independent trials" implies that this "$k$" is a binomial distribution, say $X\sim \text{Bin}(n, p)$. Recall that $\text{Var}(X) = np(1-p) = npq$, and so 
$$\text{Var}\left[\frac{X}{n}\right] = \frac{1}{n^2}\text{Var}(X) = \frac{pq}{n}.$$
Thus, applying [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality#Probabilistic_statement), we get
$$P\left[\left|\frac{X}{n}-p\right|>\epsilon\right] \leq \frac{\text{Var}(X/n)}{\epsilon^2} = \frac{pq}{n\epsilon^2}.$$

---

**Addendum:** Don't know Chebyshev's inequility? Then let me be "clever" and call $Y = \frac{X}{n}$, and notice that
\begin{align*}
P(|Y - p| \geq \epsilon)&=
E[I\{|Y - p| \geq \epsilon\}]\\
&=E\left[I\left\{\left(\frac{Y-p}{\epsilon}\right)^2\geq 1\right\}\right]\\
&\leq E\left[\left(\frac{Y-p}{\epsilon}\right)^2\right]\\
&= \frac{E[(Y-p)^2]}{\epsilon^2}\\
&=\frac{\text{Var}(Y)}{\epsilon^2}\\
&= \frac{pq}{n\epsilon^2},
\end{align*}
where $I$ is an indicator. The reality is that I was not clever and I simply adapted the many proofs of Chebyshev's inequality to show the result.
What your textbook says is an interpretation of the inequality. This is the "proof" of the result, if you want to call it that. Were you supposed to simply accept this without proof or derive it yourself? I don't know, but here it is.

Comment: Cant I understand it without variance and other things because I havent reached to that topics yet and would like to understand this theorem without them as is described before the variance and mean topics in the textbook. I know the proof with other method!!

Comment: Doubtful. Read the the notes or the preface to the text book. It might inform you on how much knowledge is required/a prerequisite to your particular textbook. It is possible that you are expected to understand this from previous studies. If this is not the expectation, then it is possible that you missed/skipped something in the textbook, or the authors have poorly presented the material.

Comment: I havent skipped anything yet, I understood what  he says about the theorem but I am not able to infer it from the inequality.....

Comment: @Stef Thanks! Got it.

Comment: edited the question @probablyme

Comment: @Jasser I have edited my response.

Comment: @Jasser After I read your edit, I think I understand your question now. You are asking how to interpret this, correct? Essentially, what the textbook is saying is that the difference between $\frac{k}{n}$ and $p$ can be made as large or as small as desired with a small or large enough $n$.

Comment: Yes exactly that question!! Yes but how do I infer it from the inequality....

Comment: @Jasser 1. The author tells you that (somewhat) explicitly. 2. You can play around with the numbers. See what happens when you plug in different values of $n$, or $\epsilon$, etc.

Comment: Thankyou you have put a good amount of effort(no one would do that)..... and I am going to try plugging numbers and also learn more about expectations, chebychevs inequality etc.... and if would then not be able to infer it even from that than I would turn up again!!

Answer (score 0):

Chebychev's inequality says the upper bound is $\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$ for $\epsilon$ standard deviations in  $P((|k-\mu|)\ge \epsilon\sigma) = P(|\frac{k}{n}-p|\ge\epsilon\sqrt{\frac{pq}{n}})$.  The standard deviation here is $\sqrt{npq}$ and $\mu = np$. For the following expression $\left(\epsilon\sqrt{\frac{pq}{n}}\right)$ standard deviations, the upper bound   still is  $\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$. But what you want is $\epsilon$.  Now take the entire remainder of $\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}\epsilon}{\sqrt{pq}}\right)\sqrt{\frac{pq}{n})}$ besides $\sqrt{\frac{pq}{n}}$ as $\epsilon'$ and apply the normal chebyshev to find the upper bound as $\frac{1}{\epsilon'^2}$,  which when you manipulate gives$\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}\epsilon}{\sqrt{pq}}\right)^2}$.  If you do some rearrangement , you get the  desired result.

Comment: edited the question @ satish ramanathan

Comment: @Jasser, This is a simple way of applying Chebychev's inequality as a proof